# Delimiting strings based on position c#

Tags: c#, string, split, delimiter

I have the following string for example

```
PT01 0200LB  Wax  N011 00000000500030011 00000000
```

I need to get the individual strings for this, based on teh following conditions

```
Position    Description

1-2         Catagory Type
3-6         Action Type
7-15        Kit Number
```

I need to get each individual strings based on these positions.
How can I proceded ?

Comment: You don't even now your desired result and haven't tried anything? What is a position, the zero based index? So the category would be `T0`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you encountering problems? Do you not know how to split strings? Do you not know how to store them? Do you want a nice way of not having to hardcode your table of conditions into your code so it can be reused for different string formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's translate the positions into zero-based index (pos1-1) and length (pos2-pos1+1):

```
Position    Description     Index  Length

1-2         Catagory Type   0      2
3-6         Action Type     2      4
7-15        Kit Number      6      9
```

Now you can use that in the `Substring` method to get a part of the string. Example:

```
string actionType = input.Substring(2, 4);
```

You might want to trim off spaces from some of the substrings. Example:

```
string actionType = input.Substring(2, 4).Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it excactly what you are looking for, because did not post the excact desired result based on your example, but this should go in the right general direction:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string CategoryType { get; set; }
    public string ActionNumber { get; set; }
    public string KitNumber { get; set; }
}
//create Dummy Data
var source = new List<string>()
{
    "PT01 0200LB  Wax  N011 00000000500030011 00000000",
    "PT02 0300LB  Bee  C011 00000000500030011 00000000",
    "PT03 0300LB  Silk  A011 00000000500030011 00000000",
    "PT04 0400LB  Cornflakes  A011 00000000500030011 00000000"
};

var result = from s in source
             select new CustomObject {
                CategoryType = s.Substring(0,2),
                ActionNumber = s.Substring(2,3),
                //read to end
                KitNumber = s.Substring(5, s.Length -6)
             };
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer, even though I don't agree with spending so much time on a badly asked question.

Comment: The second item is characters 3-6 so should be four characters long. This does admittedly give `01 0` here which looks weird but that's the spec, who am I to judge it?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't too sure either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub strings or download some ready tool like

http://www.filehelpers.net/

It has classes to parse Fixed Length files
Click "Quick Start for Fixed Length Records" on main page

And use it as follows

```
[FixedLengthRecord()] 
public class Record
{ 
    [FieldFixedLength(2)] 
    public int CategoryType; 

    [FieldFixedLength(3)] 
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)] 
    public string ActionType; 

    [FieldFixedLength(7)] 
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string KitNumber; 
 }
```

And later in your code

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Record>();
Record[] res = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt");
```

Comment: Not to discourage you from answering, but you might need to look at [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: This is a link to a tool  - i can copy paste code, of course ;)

Comment: Links to tools etc... can go under comments

Comment: Thanks, i added details to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other excellent answers, there are many ways one can perform this operation.

## Via extension method

```
/// <summary>Splits the specified string at the specified indexes.</summary>
/// <param name="str">The string to split.</param>
/// <param name="delimiters">The delimiters / Indexes to split by.</param>
/// <returns>A <see cref="T:System.string[]" /> array containing the split result.</returns>
public static string[] Split(this string str, params int[] delimiters) {
    return delimiters.Select(
        (offset, argIndex) =>
        str.Substring(
            offset,
            (argIndex < delimiters.Length - 1
                    ? delimiters[argIndex + 1] - offset
                    : str.Length - offset)))
                .ToArray();
}
```

**Usage**

```
[TestMethod]
public void SplitByDelimitersTest() {
    // Replace the spaces in this string, it makes it possible to get the data using the extension method.
    var data = "PT01 0200LB  Wax  N011 00000000500030011 00000000".Replace(" ", "");
    var result = data.Split(0, 2, 8);
    var expected = new[] { "PT", "010200", "LBWaxN0110000000050003001100000000" };
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, result, "Collections were not equal in the SplitByDelimeters test.");
}
```

## Via String.Split

```
var data = "PT01 0200LB  Wax  N011 00000000500030011 00000000";
// If you want the extra empty spcaces around "Wax" removed, simply specify StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries instead.
var split = data.Split(new [] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

var categoryType = split[0];
var actionNumber = split[1];
var kitNumber = String.Join(" ", split.Skip(2));
```

## Via RegularExpressions

```
var data = "PT01 0200LB  Wax  N011 00000000500030011 00000000";

var match = Regex.Match(data, @"(?<categoryType>..\d\d) (?<actionNumber>\d{4}..)  (?<kitNumber>.+)");

var categoryType = match.Groups["categoryType"].Value;
var actionNumber = match.Groups["actionNumber"].Value;
var kitNumber = match.Groups["kitNumber"].Value;
```

I am sure there are more ways to do this, possibly some using the neat way in Serv's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use C# Substring?

```
string splitStr = Yourstr.Substring(0,2);
```

Msdn: [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: can you please define exact description of your string...
like 
PT01 = ? 
0200LB = ?
Wax = ?  
N011 = ? 
00000000500030011 00000000 = ?

Comment: @KiranRamchandraParab Yourstr is the string you want to split.

Comment: still I did not get that... what is description in your example

Comment: @KiranRamchandraParab It's an example of how to use substring. What could be confusing about that.